# connection error while connecting to AWS DocumentDB through lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

getting the following error while connecting to AWS DocumentDB from node.js through lambda

> {"errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)","Object.fs.readFileSync
>   (fs.js:551:33)","Object.
>   (/var/task/base/mongoose.base.js:8:13)","Module._compile
>   (module.js:652:30)","Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:663:10)","Module.load (module.js:565:32)","tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:505:12)","Function.Module._load
>   (module.js:497:3)","Module.require (module.js:596:17)","require
>   (internal/module.js:11:18)","Object.
>   (/var/task/library/mongoLib/room.lib.js:1:84)","Module._compile
>   (module.js:652:30)","Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:663:10)","Module.load (module.js:565:32)","tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:505:12)","Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"]}

here is my node js file in lambda

```
var ca = fs.readFileSync(path.join('./','rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'));

var options = {
        keepAlive: true,
        poolSize: 30,
        socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
        autoReconnect: true,
        reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        reconnectInterval: 500,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        auth: {authdb: 'admin'},
        useFindAndModify: false,
        sslValidate: true,
        sslCA:ca,
        useNewUrlParser: true
}

var uri = 'mongodb://'+globalData.getConfigurationSettings("documentdb_username")+':'+globalData.getConfigurationSettings("documentdb_password")+'@'+globalData.getConfigurationSettings("documentdb_server")+':'+globalData.getConfigurationSettings("documentdb_port")+'/'+globalData.getConfigurationSettings("documentdb_db_name")+'?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred';

mongoose.connect(uri, options)
.then(() => console.log('Connection to DB successful'))
.catch((err) => console.error(err,'Error'));
```

Comment: Go to Lambda console, in `Function code`, check again path of `.pem` file

Comment: @hoangdv, it is the same folder where i'm reading it

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
var ca = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'));
```

Or you can define :

```
import caBundle from "./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem";

var options = {
            ............
            sslCA:caBundle,
```

Comment: it is same what is given above post

Comment: `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` and the file you are running are on the same folder, right ? can you share `ls -ls` in the current folder ?

Comment: 4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ***** *****  1094 Feb 27 19:01 mongoose.base.js
                                      
64 -rwxrwxrwx 1 ***** ***** 65484 Feb 12 13:20 rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem  

( mongoose.base.js -> this is the file where i'm requiring rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem )

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

it seems that file doesn't exist there. can you check the path? did you embed the cert with lambda?

Comment: i have added the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem file in the same folder